# Can jquery promises be garbage collected before they resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Consider the following:

```
function listFoo() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}

function listFooey() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}

function parallelLoad() {
    //Note that we do *not* return the promise here.
    $.when(
        listFoo(), listFooey()
    )
    .then (function(fooResponse, fooeyResponse) {
        console.log('then')
        //doStuff
    });
}

//Kick everything off and log
console.log('before parallelLoad');
parallelLoad();
console.log('after parallelLoad');
```

A typical output on the console would be ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vr8aqydf/14/)) :

```
before parallelLoad
after parallelLoad
then
```

The first two functions return the ajax `Promise`, so the reference to it is not lost.  However, the `parallelLoad()` function does not return the promise, so when it is executed, it creates the promise, returns immediately, and the promise would appear to immediately go out of scope.

In practice, I have not seen a problem arise from this pattern, but I'm wondering if that's just "luck".

In the example above, is `parallelLoad()` "safe" in that (assuming the ajax calls run without server/network errors) the `then` clause will always execute?

Or is there a race condition where sometimes the ajax calls might not even be initiated or the promises might be garbage collected before the `then` clause can run?

(Currently I am using jQuery 3.3.1)

Comment: Not sure why you think running code is going to be garbage collected.

Comment: The then will always execute, you just cannot chain anything to the end of it. If you don't need to, then thats just fine.

Comment: Just as with `setTimeout` the handler for `then` goes on the heap and associated with resolve event. When that event fires the handler is executed.

Comment: When variables leave scope it doesn't imply they get garbage collected. There's still references in the Javascript VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, promises that are not going to be resolved and are not longer needed can be garbage-collected before they are resolved.

This is not the case in your example however. Even while there is no obvious global variable holding onto the promise, it still is referenced from the running ajax requests. The requests created by `listFoo()` and `listFooey()` keep the callbacks installed on them alive, as they need to run them when they finish. In turn, these callbacks reference the promises (or at least, the deferred parts of them) and the callbacks installed on them, as they need to resolve the promises and call the callbacks when they run. In turn, these callbacks reference the promise (or deferred) created by the `$.when` call and the callback installed on it, as they still are needed until everything is settled. Only once both requests are done and all callbacks are executed, everything will be garbage-collected.

No, it can never happen that a promise will miss to invoke your callbacks because something got garbage-collected at the wrong time.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem there, the `then` will always execute.

One main obvious downside with this is since the `parallelLoad` promise is lost, there is no continuation and you cannot chain any other events to the success or failure of `listFoo, listFooey`.

I think the promise chaining style may be the cause of the confusion.

Look at it this way, if you rewrite `parallelLoad` like so (breaking the chain),

```
function parallelLoad() {
    //Note that we do *not* return the promise here.
    var whenPromise = $.when(listFoo(), listFooey());

    whenPromise.then(function(fooResponse, fooeyResponse) {
        console.log('then');
        //doStuff
    });
}
```

You can now probably easily see that the `then` part is simply just another line of code(with a callback) waiting to be called and so will not be garbage collected until it is done.

After the `then` gets called, `parallelLoad` will go out of scope for ***you***, ***but*** the references to the promises and callbacks created therein are still held internally in memory until the promises are resolved/rejected and callbacks are called.

Comment: I think where I am a bit unclear is how the `then` part of the chain "sticks around".  The ajax call immediately goes to some sort of browser queue for execution as an XMLHttpRequest under the covers, so the "browser queue" would have a reference to the underlying XMLHttpRequest even if no other javascript function did, but how does the `then` clause participate so that its execution is not "lost"?

Comment: Once `parallelLoad ` is kicked off it wont be garbage collected whilst running. Its variables and functions are also closed over(lookup closures) so they will be in memory whilst in the context of that function.
Once the `when` is done it return a promise object which the `then` gets called against.
The `fooResponse, fooeyResponse` functions in the `then` are are also closed over so the reference to them will exist until execution is completely out of scope. That was a long comment..phew!

Comment: My apologies, I messed up in my example code a bit (it had a syntax error, and I intended the example to show the then clause with a single function processing the multiple responses - your comment about capturing `fooResponse` and `fooeyReponse` made me realize the mistake.  Still trying to figure out how "then" fits into the closure stuff - I'm not seeing what creates the closure in this case, and it appears to me that `parallellLoad` returns before `then` executes, so I'm not seeing how paraellelLoad is considered to be "running" at that time.

Comment: @Nathan I think the chain style may be the cause of your confusion see the latest edit, I hope its clear enough.

Answer (score -1):

Nathan, Closures are about identifiers right? So `parallelLoad()` references both `listFoo` and `listFooey`identifiers (as functions) creating two closures. Those closures will remain in place until (at least) each of those functions complete and resolve. That means that `parallelLoad()` is the Execution Context and has not completed yet. The next step in the process is the `.then()` in response to the resolve.

That means the Execution Context (`parallelLoad()`) is established at the `parallelLoad()` call and does not change until all the code in the `.then()` has completed, it is a safe paradigm.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I see how closures have anything to do with this.  `listFoo()` and `listFooey()` are immediately executed, and the resulting `jqXHR` (Promise) is what the `when` clause "sees" - it doesn't actually "capture" any function reference.  Being asynchronous, the `then` clause won't (typically) execute until after `parallelLoad()` has already returned.  I'm not seeing how `then` is part of any closure.

Comment: Closures have **everything** to do with this. But I won't try to convince you. "Being asynchronous, the then clause won't (typically) execute until after parallelLoad() has already returned." -- your understanding of this is not accurate. Finally, I'm not sure where you inferred `then` is part of a closure since I didn't state that. The `then` is part of the Execution Context that is formed by `parallelLoad()` and remains so until `then` has completed.

Comment: But I *want* to be convinced :-)

Comment: OK. I added the `parallelLoad` lifecycle from Chrome Performance tool into my answer so you can see. The function starts executing and remains in memory until after the `then` completes. I'm guess you won't believe that either though.